# Can we do anything with $\frac{d}{db}\int_0^1e^{bx}f(x)dx$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have this monster as the part of a longer calculation. My goal would be to somehow make it... nicer.

Intuitively, I would try to somehow utilize the derivate and the integral against each other, but I have no idea, exactly how.

I suspect, this might be a relative common problem, i.e. if we want to derivate a parametrized definite integral against one of its parameters. Maybe it has even some trick... or methodology to handle it.

Of course it is not a problem if the integral remains. The primary goal would be in this stage, to eliminate or significantly simplify the derivative operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably in your calculus textbook ... under reasonable conditions,

$$
\frac{d}{db}\int_0^1e^{bx}f(x)dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial b}e^{bx}f(x)dx = \int_0^1 x e^{bx}f(x)dx
$$

Comment: "Under reasonable conditions" can be elaborated upon with this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Called the Leibnitz rule, after the first one to state it.  Sometimes called "Feynman's trick" ... because Feynman was the first physicist to publicize its use.

Comment: Wow, it is wonderful! I waited a much harder solution. :-) Btw., $f(x)$ is a sample of a real-world quantity, like the votes/month stat of a stackexchange site. Singular things are a non-issue. I hope it is enough to pass the "reasonable condition" criterium :-)

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous you can just use the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to assert: $\frac{d}{db}\int_0^1 e^{bx} f(x)dx = \int_0^1 x e^{bx} f(x)dx$

The Leibniz integral rule says that if $g$ and its partial derivatives are continuous, then 
$$
\frac{d}{d y} \int_a^b g(x,y)dx = \int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(x,y)dx
$$

Comment: Seems that I was a slow typist. GEdgar posted his answer sooner than me.

Comment: Also your answer helps a lot, for example only now I know for sure that I can use it in my current scenario. Tyvm! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I looked for a way to simplify such things, and found out that trading differentiation for integration was an efficient way to simplify the task. In your case,
\begin{align}
     \int_{0}^{1}e^{bx}f(x)dx &= \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{b}xe^{cx}dc+1\right) f(x)dx\\
   & = \int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{1}e^{cx}xf(x)dx dc+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx.
\end{align}
The function $c\mapsto \int_{0}^{1}e^{cx}xf(x)dx$ is a continuous function of $c$. So the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus now implies that the left side is differentiable in $b$ because the right side is, and
$$
    \frac{d}{db}\int_{0}^{1}e^{bx}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}e^{bx}xf(x)dx.
$$
It turns out that trading differentiation for integration in this way is a handy way to justify such operations. Continuity in $c$ of the function mentioned above also follows from integral theorems.

Comment: Would it be possible to use this technique to prove the Leibniz integral rule in general?

Comment: @Hashimoto : Yes. The theorems of integrals, especially interchanging orders of integration, are more sophisticated and easier to apply. So reducing the problem to one of integration does simplify such types of problems.